# use varargs can loose type-checking in compile time?

Tags: java, arrays, java-5

In the [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) book, Item 42 talks about varargs method.

It says:

```
ReturnType1 suspect1(Object... args){}
<T> ReturnType2 suspect2(T... args){}
```

> Methods with either of these signatures will accept any parameter
>   list. Any compile-time type-checking that you had prior to the
>   retrofit will be lost.

I get confused.

**Question one:**
why retrofit/refactor method to varargs could loose type-checking had before in the method? In above two method singature, isn't `Object`  and `T` the type specified there? In which way we could loose type-checking exactly? The book explained that by referring to an example author made but I don't get it:

======= the example author use to convince readers =======

the author made an example of `Arrays.asList(...)`, that **before Java 1.5**, the following code would raise compile time error for type checking:

```
int[] digits = {3,1,4}
// Compiler error: asList(Object[]) in Arrays can't be applied to (int[])
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(digits));
```

and since **java1.5 and above**, due to the introduction of `varargs`, the above code is fine with compiler. The `Arrays.asList(digits)` wraps the whole `int[]` to one object so that the `Arrays.asList(digits)` returns a one-element array of arrays `List<int[]>`.

**Question two:**
I understand this example, it indeed is an example of loosing type-checking, but the action of wrapping primitive int array(`digits`) to an object is conducted by `Arrays.asList()` method, not the `vargars` usage (or am I wrong here?), why the author use this example to say the all methods with those two signatures can loose type-checking during compiler time?  how? Any examples to convince me?

Comment: *"but the action of wrapping primitive int array(digits) to an object is conducted by Arrays.asList() method"*: not sure what you mean... Without the var-args, the signature won't match the `int[]` parameter. But I see that the illustration of the problem is quite tenuous... Are you just looking for different illustrations of this (i.e., other than `primitive[]` arguments for `Reference[]` parameters, generic or not)?

Comment: @ernest_k, yes I am looking for a different illustrations for that if you could provide one would be nice :)

Comment: Do you mean *'lose'*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In above two method singature, isn't Object and `T` the type specified
>   there?

Sort of, but not really. The `T` will be erased at runtime. A simple example is `Arrays.asList(1, 2L, "3")` which packs an `Integer`, `Long` and `String`. This results in the compile-time type of `T` becoming `<Serializable & Comparable>` (which is the supertype of all those 3 classes). So depending on what you pass, the `T` "adapts" becoming `Object` in the widest case.

> ..the action of wrapping primitive int array(digits) to an object is
>   conducted by Arrays.asList() method, not the vargars usage (or am I
>   wrong here?)

`Arrays.asList()` will just assign each element in the input array to a list. Due to varargs, the `int[] {1, 2, 3}` will be one element (so `T` becomes `int[]` since `int` is not an object, as opposed to `Integer {1, 2, 3}` where `T` becomes `Integer`). Of course the code could be written so that it checks if there's a single input element, then checks if it's an array, then converts `int[]` to `List<Integer>`, but that would break the generics (`int[]` becomes `Integer` suddenly), and that wouldn't be the only problem with it.

Comment: So, do you mean the author is actually saying only if the method accepting primitive array as arguments could loose type-checking after switched to `varargs`, otherwise not?

Comment: @Leem.fin no, primitive arrays are one problematic thing, the type erasure is just normal generics work.

Comment: But how NOT using varargs don't yield this issue? The point of the author is that using varargs could bring the issue. Why it is varargs specific issue? That's my main concern of my question.

Comment: @Leem.fin because varargs is syntactic sugar on the top of a `Object[]`. You can recreate the same effect by using `Object[] params` parameters in methods. No type safety there either. Of course note that you can give a bound to the type parameter, so `<T extends Number>` would give you an upper bound of `Number` and not `Object`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So, I feel it is confusing to the readers if author tries to say it like it is varargs specific issue in the context. Because without varargs e.g. Object[] , T[], it is the same issue unless author means for primitive parameters.

Comment: @Leem.fin but it's with varargs where it can bite you in the ass the easiest, and without warning. The example with the primitive array is telling, because we know that `int[]` is not an `Object[]` as in pre-1.5, but `int[]` **is** `T` (i.e. `Object`).

Comment: right, "without warning" is the convincing part to me.

Comment: I also think it isn't a good example. With `asList(Object[])` it is possible to use different types and it will work. It is even possible to pass `Integer[]` and it will work as **Arrays are covariant in Java**. The only thing that wouldn't work in pre 1.5 was trying to assign `int[]` to `Object[]`parameter type (stll doesn't work) but it is possible to assign `int[]` to `Object... args` with the introduction of  `varargs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReturnType1 suspect1(Object... args){}
```

Since all objects inherit from the `Object` class, its useless for the compiler to perform the compile-time type-checking.

```
<T> ReturnType2 suspect2(T... args){}
```

Also here, the variable type `T` may be everything you want at *runtime* therefore its useless for the compiler to check the type.

To know If using vararg you lose type-checking, write a few lines of code using vararg and deliberately pass not allowed types as vararg: you'll see if the compiler fails o if will be thrown an exception at runtime.

Comment: Yep, but why do I need to care about type checking if the two methods are apparently used in a more generic way (e.g. in a generic class or generalized class)? I feel the author is trying to say any method including those with a concrete type as long as having that KIND of signature could loose type-checking, that confuses me.

Comment: I think the type-check at compile time can only be performed with known data or types that can be predicted. With those two signatures he can't. If you don't specify the type as `Object`, but something more specific, I really doubt the compiler don't perform type-checking... also if there is a vararg. Did you tried to use the `?` wildcard for generics? e.g. `ReturnType1 suspect1(<? extends MyType> ... args){}`?

Comment: I am thinking that my method is `<T> ReturnType2 suspect2(T[] params)`, how can author say that if I now swtich to use varargs I could loose type checking? Before and after using varargs, my example are both generic type `T`. That's what I don't understand. I think they are identical regarding to type-checking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a type system subject.

It is possible to assign `new Object[]{1, 2L, "3"}` to `Object[]` and it is also possible to assign `new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}` to `Object[]` as **Arrays are covariant in Java**. It isn't possible to assign `int[]` to `Object[]`, but it is possible to assign `int[]` to `Object... args`.

A method which takes `Object[]` as a parameter will accept an array of Objects of any type, before or after Java 1.5. But a method which takes `Object... args` as a parameter (only after Java 1.5) can also accept `int[]`.